Can't able to set particular section at the bottom of last page of pdf
Can't able to set particular section at the bottom of last page of pdf, i am using playwright package for template in python,i am not able to show this section bottom of the page it shows at the content ends but want last page at the bottom
Can't able to set particular section at the bottom of last page of pdf, i am using playwright package for template in python, firstly i tried this but it appeared below the contents end but i want at the bottom of the page so applied bottom:0,position:fixed, but it shows all the pages and i want it only last page and secondly i am tried another way still not working
 <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="section-7">
            <div class="section-7-left center">Receiver's Sign</div>
            <div class="section-7-center center">Rubber Stamp</div>
            <div class="section-7-right center">Authorised Signatory</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

css -  .section-7 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
        margin-top: 70px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        width: 100%;
       }

      .section-7-left {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
       }

      .section-7-center {
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
      }

      .section-7-right {
        grid-column: 3 / 4;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
another way- footer_template = """
<style>
    .footer-wrapper {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: calc(100% - 2cm);
        margin: 0 1cm;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .section-7 {
        display: none; /* Hide by default */
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .section-7-left, .section-7-center, .section-7-right {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .footer-content {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .fw-bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div id="lastPageSection" class="section-7">
        <div class="section-7-left">Receiver's Sign</div>
        <div class="section-7-center">Rubber Stamp</div>
        <div class="section-7-right">Authorised Signatory</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-content">
        <p class="fw-bold">Powered By TECHstile.in</p>
        <p>This is a Computer Generated Invoice</p>
        <p>{{invoice_number}}-
        <strong><span class="pageNumber"></span>/<span class="totalPages"></span></strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function() {
        var pageNumber = parseInt(document.querySelector('.pageNumber').textContent);
        var totalPages = parseInt(document.querySelector('.totalPages').textContent);
        if (pageNumber === totalPages) {
            document.getElementById('lastPageSection').style.display = 'grid';
        }
    })();
</script>
"""


Where is your Playwright code? Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. Please don't repeat the same question twice to bypass filters--actually provide the details we need to reproduce this.

def create_playwright_invoice_pdf(html_content, pdf_path, data: dict):
with sync_playwright() as p:
browser = p.chromium.launch()
page = browser.new_page()
page.set_content(html_content)
template = Template(footer_template)

in this footer_template i given in above code

Please [edit] that code into the post. What is the definition of Template?

from jinja2 import Template  we can create template using jinja2 template\
